# Convert datetime which is in varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server

This is my query

```
select cast('2014/07/30 13:57:38.893000' as datetime)
```

Above query returns an error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision specified in the string can be handled by a `Datetime2` which is why `Datetime2` was added to SQL Server 2008:

```
select cast('2014/07/30 13:57:38.893000' as datetime2)
```

From the SQL Server 
[Transact SQL Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx):

Character length:
19 positions minimum (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`) to 27 maximum (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0000000`)

Answer (score 0):

That's too much precision for the parser to understand.

Just try it like this:

```
select cast('2014/07/30 13:57:38.893' as datetime)
```

Comment: yes , select cast('2014/07/30 13:57:38.893' as datetime)

Comment: select cast('2014/07/30 13:57:38.893' as datetime) 
It's working but in our database all dates store in above format like
2014/07/30 13:57:38.893000 
so What is the solution to convert this value to datetime

Comment: Try either @ptilton's solution or Rahul Tripathi's solution. It depends on whether you want to keep the precision or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @s varchar(30)
set @s = '2014/07/30 13:57:38.893000'
select cast(LEFT(@s,LEN(@s)-3) as datetime)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2178)**